# how to solve SSRS Expression issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I wanted Council Rates to be EXCLUDED from the report formulas if `LEASETYPE = Gross`

Currently the expression is this,

```
=IIF((RTRIM(Fields!COMPANY_NAME.Value))="VACANT","",Fields!COUNCIL_RATES_PA.Value)
```

Comment: I have been observed that, you are just asking question! Have you checked last question's answer? If any of the answer helps to you then please mark it as answer.

Comment: oh i am really sorry i am new here and i don't know this feature !!

Comment: now thanks to u i know it !!

Comment: Here EXCLUDED  means? You don't want to show `Council Rates` if `LEASETYPE = Gross` ??

Comment: yes.......correct !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
=IIF(RTRIM(Fields!COMPANY_NAME.Value)="VACANT","",IIF(Fields!LEASETYPE.Value="Gross",Nothing,Fields!COUNCIL_RATES_PA.Value))
```

Comment: could u explain what this expression doing?                                                     thanks in advance !!

Comment: `IIF(Fields!LEASETYPE.Value="Gross",Nothing,Fields!COUNCIL_RATES_PA.Value)` - If LEASETYPE will be Gross then it will show nothing. in rest of the cases it will show COUNCIL_RATES_PA value

Comment: not able to connect to workplace server sorry will try it tomorrow !!